# How can I make a ListView's columns auto-resize programmatically?

Tags: .net, windows, user-interface, controls

I've found some examples using the Win32 api or simulating the ^+ button combination (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>+</kbd>) [using SendKeys](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/AutoResize.aspx), but at least with the SendKeys method the listview grabs the cursor and sets it to an hourglass until I hit the start button on my keyboard.  What is the cleanest way to do this?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what "auto-resize" means? Do you mean you want them to shuffle around when the window (and list view) change size, or do you want them to resize based on the length of the data they're showing?

Comment: I want them to resize based on the length of the data they're showing.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Looks like a call to `myListView.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent)` will do what you want. I would think, just call it after adding an item.

More info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.autoresizecolumns(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Should be ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle::ColumnContent

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.columnheader.width(VS.71).aspx), if you set the column width to -1 then it will  autosize to the widest item

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me.  I'm adding listviewitems at run-time and the columns stay skinny.

Comment: Weird. Perhaps the ListView needs to be visible and with the items added already. Or perhaps a call to Application.DoEvents might do the trick?

You could always try sending LVSCW_AUTOSIZE yourself using P/Invoke: http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html?code/comctl/lvcolumnautosize.htm (link for VB6)

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the list view updates in BeginUpdate()/EndUpdate() brackets? Maybe the -1 trick works when you specifically end the update, triggering a recalc of the way the list view is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

loop through all columns and set width to -1 after adding content.

Answer (score 0):

After adding the following routine to your code then call it from any procedure/function. Do not use it in your "Form_Load" procedure though. Only call it after you have added an item to your ListView (or if you are making multiple additions, call it once at the end of all the additions):

```
    Private Sub AutoSizeListViewColumns(oListView As ListView)
        Dim nCol As Integer = 0
        SuspendLayout()
        For nCol = 0 To (oListView.Columns.Count - 1)
            oListView.Columns(nCol).Width = -1  'forces autosizing on column
        Next
        oListView.Refresh()
        ResumeLayout()
    End Sub
```